# Two-part conditional sql statement

Tags: sql, group-by, conditional-statements, case, where-clause

The statement below is querying a log table and I'm trying to get the max budget depending on the scenario if falls within.

Error message:

> Expressions referencing the outer query are not supported outside of WHERE/HAVING clause

```
SELECT
    id, status, budget,
    CASE 
        WHEN (status == 'RUNNING' AND status == 'NOT RUNNING') 
            THEN (SELECT MAX(budget) 
                  FROM status_table 
                  WHERE status == 'RUNNING')
        WHEN (status == 'RUNNING') 
            THEN (SELECT MAX(budget) 
                  FROM status_table 
                  WHERE status == 'RUNNING')
        WHEN (status == 'NOT RUNNING') 
            THEN (SELECT MAX(budget) 
                  FROM status_table 
                  WHERE status == 'NOT RUNNING')
        ELSE MAX(budget)
    END AS max_budget
FROM 
    status_table 
GROUP BY
    id, status, budget
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you want to find the row(s) with the maximum `budget` where the `status` is either *RUNNING* or *NOT RUNNING*.

```sql
SELECT id
      ,status
      ,budget
  FROM status_table
 WHERE budget = (
                  SELECT max(budget)
                    FROM (
                           SELECT max(budget)
                             FROM status_table
                            WHERE status = 'RUNNING'
                           UNION
                           SELECT max(budget)
                             FROM status_table
                            WHERE status = 'NOT RUNNING'
                         )
                )
```

Comment: I have 3 scenarios, 1)when an ID's status can flip flops between "running" and "not running" , I want the max budget of the "running" row [my first case when clause] 2)  an ID's status remains either "running" or "not running" and does not flip flop, then take the max budget of either status [other two clauses]